# How to display additional digits of a floating point number?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I have a [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) which I created like this:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble( "27.86753" ); // All the digits of this double value are 27.867530822753906
```

This particular double can also be represented by a float, so Java drops the rest of my digits.  How can I force Java to give me the true double representation (all of the digits) of this value?

Comment: Have you got this figured out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, man, interesting.  You want to learn exactly how `double` does it *inaccurately.*

I think `new BigDecimal(double).toString()` will give you all of the incorrect digits, since `BigDecimal` represents a number with a precisely specified precision.

EDIT:  Ohhhhhhhh, I think I see what's going on.

Let me try to explain it like this: `Double.toString` returns the least precise `String` such that `Double.parseDouble` will return exactly the same `double` -- *just* enough digits to "uniquely identify" the exact IEEE 754 value, though the actual value may have more digits than are printed.  Just because `Double.toString` isn't giving you as many digits as you expect doesn't mean that the *actual* IEEE 754 double-precision value is being rounded to that many digits.  `new BigDecimal(double).toString` will return the exact IEEE-754 value being stored.

UPDATE:

What's going on is that when it prints out `27.86753`, it's actually internally a *more* precise value than the digits you're quoting as the correct answer, `27.867530822753906`.  That's just because `toString` is designed to print out only as much as necessary to ensure that `Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(value))` is a no-op.

I ran the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double dWithFloat = Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(Float.parseFloat("27.86753")));
  double dJustParsed = Double.parseDouble("27.86753");
  System.out.println(dWithFloat);
  System.out.println(dJustParsed);

  BigDecimal bigFromFloat = new BigDecimal(dWithFloat);
  BigDecimal bigJustParsed = new BigDecimal(dJustParsed);
  System.out.println(bigFromFloat); 
    // prints the exact value from the double,
    // doesn't round or truncate like Double.toString
  System.out.println(bigJustParsed);
```

}

and it printed out

```
27.867530822753906 // Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(Float.parseFloat("27.86753"))));
27.86753 // Double.toString(Double.parseDouble("27.86753")) is indeed a no-op
27.86753082275390625 // This is the _actual_ value from D.parseD(D.toString(F.parseF("27.86753")))
27.867529999999998580051396857015788555145263671875 // This is the actual value from D.parseD("27.86753")
```

And indeed, this second value is noticeably closer to 27.86753, by a margin of something like 0.0000008.

Comment: That gives me a bunch of digits ( 27.867529999999998580051396857015788555145263671875 ), but it isn't the IEEE 754 double value of 27.867530822753906 I am looking for.

Comment: Where are you getting that other value from?  I'd be strongly inclined to trust `BigDecimal` on this.

Comment: Um.  That link just goes to the Java Double class page.  Not sure what you're referring to.  UPDATE: I think I understand your confusion now.

Comment: Oops!  Here is the correct link to the [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html).

Comment: The second sentence of that page says that it's limited to single-precision numbers for space reasons.  I know it says "with double precision," but I don't think it's correct.  Look at it this way: `Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(value))` is _supposed_ to be a no-op, so of course it's going to print out `27.86753`.

Comment: Update: I used a decompiler on the source of that applet.  It does return `Double.toString(Float.valueOf(string))`, which is really not what you're looking for -- it does the _parsing_ as a float.

Comment: I agree what you are saying is correct.  Unfortunately I have inherited some code that is doing displaying a 32 bit "double" (ugh... it hurts to say it) in one part of the program and I needed to replicate the same behavior in another part of the program, so the answer I posted is correct for my specific situation.  I was aware there was an issue with the code immediately (since it is dealing with floats, not doubles) but I was not aware how bad it actually was until reading your post :(  Oh well, just gotta work with what I got :)

Comment: Ewwwww.  I see, now.  Sorry for the confusion, and best of luck with your depressing code.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using **`java.math.BigDecimal`** where you have explicit ways to control scale and rounding rules. You cannot do it with Double.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but it works:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble( Double.toString( Float.parseFloat( "27.86753" ) ) ); // Sets the value of the Double to 27.867530822753906
```

Comment: (This is _not_ what you want, FYI.)

Comment: This is actually what I wanted, but it is not what most people will want.  If you want the REAL double use Louis' answer.  My answer only provides the 32 bit representation of a floating point number.